# VS Not Recognizing Built-in Moduels

Tags: python, visual-studio, import

I am experimenting with importing different modules but have run into an issue with VS. Previously I would get unresolved import error when using files in the same dir. Even with these errors my program would still run. But now when using built in Python modules with VS I now get NameError. I have searched for a while and can't seem to figure out my exact issue because it seemingly should be very simple to fix. All of the import errors or NameError's I have read about are with much more complicated code.

```
from random import shuffle

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
random.shuffle(my_list)
print(my_list)
```

Any idea's on why VS is not importing modules correctly? The issue is specifically with line 4 because "random" is not defined as the error states. I am using windows 10 with the latest versions of both Python and VS.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The whole point of using `from random import shuffle` is to not make `random` available in the module that is importing's namespace. So, `from some_module import some_name` only adds `some_name` to the namespace (although, of course, it executes all if `some_module`)

Comment: So just change to `import random`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand this but I am more so thinking about my use of modules in the future. If I want to specifically import shuffle method only instead of all of random, what is wrong with the way I imported it? Sorry if this is an obvious question I am still very new to all of this haha

Comment: As I already explained, `random` won't be available if you `from random import shuffle`, only `shuffle`. If you want random available, you should do `import random`

Comment: Yes thank you I understand now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 1 you are saying

```py
from random import shuffle
```

so you are importing function shuffle() and to use it you need to call it like:

```py
shuffle(my_list)
print(my_list)
```

For calling the function like:

```
random.shuffle(my_list)
```

you need to import the whole package

```py
import random
```

Comment: Ahh this is so simple I can't believe I overlooked this. Thank you very much for the explanation

Answer (score -1):

Also I might add, you can `from` random `import` *. That will import everything from random library, but it's not as clean.